# Parsing a deeply nested xml file using a for loop

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

How could I efficiently pull data from the nested xml?
By efficiently, I mean for example using a for loop.
Would I need to make use a of new data structure?

Parsing function:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

it = ET.iterparse('OTA_AirSeatMapRS.xml')

# This for loop removes the namespaces
for _, el in it:
    _, _, el.tag = el.tag.rpartition('}')
root = it.root

# I am not able to select data with this loop
for x in element.find(Service):
    print(x)
```

This is part of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:OTA_AirSeatMapRS Version="1"
            xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/common/">
            <ns:Success/>
            <ns:SeatMapResponses>
                <ns:SeatMapResponse>
                    <ns:FlightSegmentInfo DepartureDateTime="2020-11-22T15:30:00" FlightNumber="1179">
                        <ns:DepartureAirport LocationCode="LAS"/>
                        <ns:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="IAH"/>
                        <ns:Equipment AirEquipType="739"/>
                    </ns:FlightSegmentInfo>
                    <ns:SeatMapDetails>
                        <ns:CabinClass Layout="AB EF" UpperDeckInd="false">
                            <ns:RowInfo CabinType="First" OperableInd="true" RowNumber="1">
                                <ns:SeatInfo BlockedInd="false" BulkheadInd="false" ColumnNumber="1" ExitRowInd="false" GalleyInd="false" GridNumber="1" PlaneSection="Left">
                                    <ns:Summary AvailableInd="false" InoperativeInd="false" OccupiedInd="false" SeatNumber="1A"/>
                                    <ns:Features>Window</ns:Features>
                                </ns:SeatInfo>
```

My eventual goal is to use the parsed data to store in a JSON.

Comment: Can you tell us more about exactly what you're trying to do? Why are you trying to strip namespaces? That seems like it's going make it harder to usefully parse the document.

Comment: There is [no single way to convert XML to JSON](http://wiki.open311.org/JSON_and_XML_Conversion/). You'll get better help if you provide a small, legal XML input and the  desired JSON output, along with the code you have used to try to perform the conversion. Also, there are Python libraries to convert XML to JSON. Search the internet and you might find a quick solution that works for your needs.

Comment: @larsks I was just trying to make it simpler to parse the document by removing namespaces but this may be misguided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following instruction in your code:

```
for x in element.find(Service):
```

The first flaw in your code sample is that:

- *Service* is a **variable** (not a string literal),
- probably you initialized this variable to some string, but failed
  to put this instruction in your code sample.

The source of another flaw is that *find* finds the **first** element
matching the given path, so you should not use it in a loop.
Maybe you should also check whether *find* returned some not-*None*
content, but this is another detail.

The third reason why you got the empty outptut is that *print(x)*
prints actually only the **text** of the element in question.

So to have a more general example, run:

```
Service = 'Summary'
x = root.find(f'.//{Service}')
print(f'{x.tag}, {x.text}, {x.attrib}')
```

The first instruction sets the tag name.

The second instruction invokes *find*, but note that I added *'.//'*
to the XPath, to look at **any depth** of the source XML tree.

And the last instruction prints not only text of the element found,
but also the tag name and attributes.

The result I got (for your input XML) is:

```
Summary, None, {'AvailableInd': 'false', 'InoperativeInd': 'false', 'OccupiedInd': 'false', 'SeatNumber': '1A'}
```

(*text* is just *None*, so you didn't see any result in your original
output).

Comment: I just did it! :)